# Error got when I finished the tutorial with sample React single-page application using Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, single-page-application

I tried two times with this tutorial to Configure authentication in a sample React single-page application by using Azure Active Directory B2C.

Please check the link for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-react-spa-app.

When I completed the tutorial, and the final step when I clicked the popup with sign-in, and it did not appear also shows the error "ClientAuthError: endpoints_resolution_error: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check the network and try again. Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints"

Please help me figure out the error, the result is expected like the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `ClientAuthError: endpoints_resolution_error: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check the network and try again. Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints` indicates that the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) was unable to resolve the endpoints for the Azure Active Directory (AAD) tenant that your application is trying to authenticate to.

Here is the code that i used  to resolve and to able to login without any error

// app.js

```
import  React  from  'react';
import { useMsal } from  '@azure/msal-react';
import { InteractionStatus } from  "@azure/msal-browser";

function  AuthButton() {
const { instance, accounts, inProgress, isAuthenticated } =  useMsal(); 
const  login  =  async () => {
if (!isAuthenticated  &&  inProgress  ===  InteractionStatus.None  &&  accounts.length  ===  0) {
await  instance.loginPopup();
}
};
const  logout  = () => {
instance.logoutPopup();
};
return (

<div>
{accounts.length === 0 ? (
<button  onClick={login}>Login</button>
) : (
<button  onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
)}
</div>
);
}
export  default  AuthButton;
```

MSAL.js

```
const config = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'your-client-id',
    authority: 'https://your-b2c-tenant.b2clogin.com/your-b2c-tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_your-policy',
    redirectUri: 'Your redirectUri',
  },
};
const app = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(config);
```

**Start the Development Server**

```
npm start
```

**Result**
[image]

[image]

[image]